# Number of permutations taken r at a time with repeated objects?

Tags: statistics, permutations

I've just started statistics, so bear with me if I'm a little slow on the uptake.

I've found formulae for permutations with repeated objects, formulae for permutations within a fixed space, but I haven't found formulae connecting the two.

Given n objects, with numbers of repeated objects n1, n2, n3 and so on and so forth, how can I find out the number of permutations possible when the objects are taken r at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I shall illustrate by an example of finding the number of 6 letter words in MISSISSIPPI.

The word has $1 M,\;\; 2 P's,\;\; 4 I's\;\; \text{and}\;\; 4 S's,$

and the answer using the generating function formula is

$\text{coefficient of}\;\; x^6\;\; \text{in}\;\; 6!(1+x)^1(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!})^1(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!})^2$

*PS*:

I am giving the general formula, but not able to format properly, so bear with it !

let the number of repeated objects be $n_1 , n_2, n_3, ..... n_k,$ summing up to $n$ and we want permutations of $r$ of them taken at a time, then the number of permutations is given by the

$$\text{coefficient of x^r in}\;\; r!\prod_{i=1}^k(1 +x +\frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!} + .... \frac{x^{n_i}}{n_i!})$$

Comment: Could you add a general formula in your answer? I'll accept it as soon as you do so.

Comment: Added as PS in answer